# PHP : copy data of one $result into another $result1 or array []

Tags: php, arrays, copy, odbc

I have result of an odbc query `$result` Once I fetch the data, I cannot again use the $result. As such, I tried copying the `$result.$result1 = $result;`

```
if(is_resource($result1))
{  
    while($rowhr1 = odbc_fetch_array ($result1)) 
    { 
                ?><pre><?php print_r($rowhr1); ?></pre><?php 
    }
}

if(is_resource($result))
{  
    while($rowhr = odbc_fetch_array ($result)) 
    { 
                ?><pre><?php print_r($rowhr); ?></pre><?php 
    }
}
```

The second array is empty. Please advice, how can I copy data of one $result into another $result1 or array?

This should be done in **CODE** not in **SQL**. Some third party provides me the SQL.

Comment: where is your $result and $result1 declared  ?

Comment: or you could just fetch the rows first, put it inside an array or whatever container and make copies to your heart's content